# Transforming authorizedKey field in array using jq

Tags: json, jq

Given the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "authorizedKey": "0",
    "description": "This key is for system testing.",
    "keyExpiration": "2035-02-02T18:28:59Z",
    "keyId": "aaa12345-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab"
  },
  {
    "authorizedKey": "1",
    "description": "This key is for system testing.",
    "keyExpiration": "2035-02-02T18:28:59Z",
    "keyId": "bbb12345-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab"
  },
  {
    "authorizedKey": "1",
    "description": "This key is for system testing.",
    "keyExpiration": "2035-02-02T18:28:59Z",
    "keyId": "ccc12345-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab"
  }
]
```

Using only `jq`, is there a way to transform it to the following structure? 
 Or would I need to wrap it in some kind of external logic?

```
[
  {
    "authorizedKey": "zero",
    "description": "This key is for system testing.",
    "keyExpiration": "2035-02-02T18:28:59Z",
    "keyId": "aaa12345-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab"
  },
  {
    "authorizedKey": "one",
    "description": "This key is for system testing.",
    "keyExpiration": "2035-02-02T18:28:59Z",
    "keyId": "bbb12345-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab"
  },
  {
    "authorizedKey": "one",
    "description": "This key is for system testing.",
    "keyExpiration": "2035-02-02T18:28:59Z",
    "keyId": "ccc12345-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab"
  }
]
```

Comment: Are `"0"` and `"1"` the only values you expect to find?

Comment: Not necessarily but there shouldn't be a huge number unique values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
map(. + {authorizedKey: {"0": "zero", "1": "one"}[.authorizedKey]})
```

If there are other values besides 0 and 1, you can add them to the map. If you have a bunch more and you want to improve readability, you could do this:

```
{"0": "zero", "1": "one"} as $mapping |
  map(. + {authorizedKey: $mapping[.authorizedKey]})
```

which avoids writing the value-mapping in the middle of the code.

This works because the `+` operator is defined on objects in jq, and if a key in the RHS already exists in the LHS, its value is replaced with the corresponding value from the RHS.